# Trim null characters from a string in VBA

Tags: vba, string

I'm calling a Win32 API function and getting back a string padded with null characters.  `Trim$()` doesn't remove them.  Is there an easier solution then removing them one character at a time?

Comment: Can you show some sample code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if it's just padded to the right, you can use something like this:

```
function ntrim(byval theString as string) as string
  dim iPos as long
  iPos = instr(theString, chr$(0))
  if iPos > 0 then theString = left$(theString, iPos - 1)
  ntrim = theString
end function
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'd like to think I would have come up with that if I hadn't stayed up so late writing code...

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all nulls from the string, strWithNulls.
I have also used it to convert from unicode to single byte characters.

```
strResult = Replace( strWithNulls, Chr$(0), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Loosely based on the last one, maybe this might be better if there's a risk you might have NULLs in your text for some other reason?

```
Function nTrim2(theString As String) As String
    Dim iPos As Long
    iPos = Len(theString)
    For i = iPos To 0 Step -1
        iPos = i
        If Mid$(theString, i, 1) <> Chr$(0) Then Exit For
    Next
    nTrim2 = Left$(theString, iPos)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case Replace() and InStr() don't work with Chr(0) (can't see it not displaying any error), but Nulls can be removed comparing and using Mid(), Left() and Len() as above or in this example:

```
If Mid$(str, 1, 1) = Chr$(0) Then str = Mid$(str, 2)
If Mid$(str, Len(str), 1) = Chr$(0) Then str = Left$(str, Len(str) - 1)
```

This is Null removal from ends, for example from `objFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")` value, like "?600 x 400?". Nulls (?) are insterted here in Windows 10 but not in Windows XP.